# Is there a recipe to roughly plot a family of ogives with the same median but larger standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

Given an ogive (cumulative frequency versus mass of 120 snails collected) as follows. I deliberately made the screenshot bigger so you can spot the intersection better (if you need it).

[image]

I am interested in roughly plotting a families of other possible ogives with the same sample of 120 snails and the same median but with larger standard deviation.

## Question

Is there such a guideline to do so? I know that mean must be found first because standard deviation measures the spread of data about the mean.  Unfortunately I cannot find the mean at glance without calculation.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the standard deviation by factor $k$ is increasing the spread of the data.

If all you want is for the median to be kept constant, then spread everything away from the median.

Let $M$ be the median.

You have data points $(x_i,y_i)$.

Change them all to $(k(x_i-M)+M,y_i)$

Comment: This will change the mean unless it happens to be equal to the median.